# Redirecting "wrong" but working links to their canonical URL in order to prevent search engine penalties (e.g. /123/ at the end of URLs)

Tags: permalinks, url-rewriting, redirect, seo

The WordPress permalink system is really nice as it even detects minor problems with URLs and is loading the correct page. For example we have a page with an URL like this:

> http://www.example.com/2018/01/03/mysql-phpmyadmin-how-to-import-and-export-sql-dumps-fast-and-secure/

If we type

> http://www.example.com/2018/01/03/mysql-phpmyadmin-how-to-import/

or

> http://www.example.com/2018/mysql-phpmyadmin-how-to-import-and-export-sql-dumps-fast-and-secure/

into the Browser console we are also redirected to the correct page. Nice!

However if we type

> http://www.example.com/2018/01/03/mysql-phpmyadmin-how-to-import-and-export-sql-dumps-fast-and-secure/1212/

With a random number at the end we are not redirected (though the correct page or post is displayed). The marketing guys of our company told me that this *might be bad for SEO duplicate content issues*? Why are those links not redirected and can/should I prevent this?

Comment: As long as you provide a canonical url, you should be fine as SE won't see this as duplicate content.

Comment: @mistertaylor: .... would already make quite a good answer, though it does not yet explain this behaviour of WordPress.

Comment: it's pagination - you're trying to access page 1212 of the post. The Debug Bar plugin is quite useful for diagnosing this type of behaviour.

Comment: @mistertaylor: Thanks a lot how couldn't I think of that. Make an answer from that if you want 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ensure that you provide a canonical url - this should ensure that search engines don't see the url variants as duplicate content.

Additionally, appending a number on the url, will make Wordpress try to access that page.

Using a debug plugin, such as [Debug Bar](https://en-gb.wordpress.org/plugins/debug-bar/), is quite useful for diagnosing this kind of behaviour as it will show the query performed on each page.